# Wordpress in different languages

Tags: wordpress, ftp, po, mo

I am currently working on a wordpress website in Czech language, I ran into a problem. Most of the website is in Czech. Its running good. I needed a plugin that has users and accounts that they could take care of. I started messing around with Ultimate Member (version 2.0). Most of the plugin translated, yet some things stayed in english. I also went through to translate the .mo and .po files.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, some plugin parts are in english, but the files are fully translated. Any ideas? Suggestions? It's driving me mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check the plugin 'Ultimate Member' and it does not have Czech translations. You might have to make your own translation files.

you can go to https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember and then fork the plugin. Make a czech version of https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/blob/master/languages/ultimatemember-en_US.po named as https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/blob/master/languages/ultimatemember-cs_CZ.po with correct translation. Submit a Pull request and the plugin maintainers will help to bring an update.

You can also make your own translations https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Comment: Thank you. May I message you if I need any further assistance?

Comment: How about the .mo file?

Comment: Which of these should I translate? 
msgid "text here"
msgstr "text here"

Comment: And should I keep the .mo file as "ultimatemember-en_US.mo" or rename it to "ultimatemember-cs_CZ.mo" + Do I have to change the .mo file anyhow?

Comment: Enter msgstr field with new language. Make a copy with name "ultimatemember-cs_CZ.mo"

Comment: I uploaded the files to google drive, could you take a peak at it, because it seems to do absolutely nothing... :(

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PWD0Rp8b1FeREl-a2p-Hp7hphCU4p9nZ?usp=sharing

Comment: Let me look at it.

Comment: Please try this. https://drive.google.com/open?id=14UnH2S4bilhsgzF5NWn-ubFN0_fvE8CW I have shared this with the plugin developers so an update might come through.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.  Where the .mo file wasn’t registering.

1. Make sure you change the site language in the wp-config file - not just the setting —> General.  I had to code the language into the wp-config.
2. Double check you formatted the end of the Mo file correctly - poedit likes to use hyphens but you need an underscore.  And
3. I would go look at another plugin that is translating and look in the Languages folder and see if the file names are the same.
4. See if you are naming your file the same name as other translations.

These are all the things I struggled with when I made my site into Chinese.

Good luck.  It looks like you have good help!